# What is the :: used for in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I understand keywords in Clojure being `:keyword`.  But what is the `::` used for? Why does it look like it has a binding?

```clj
user=> :foo
:foo
user=> ::foo
:user/foo
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The double colon is there [to fully qualify keywords](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/05/Did_you_know_III.html) with your current namespace. This is intended to avoid name clashes for keywords which are meaningful for different libraries. Without fully qualified keywords you might accidentally overwrite some values in a map and break compatibility with a library.

Comment: As to the provided rationale, not quite sure why in the first place would one tinker a map that a library is supposed to handle for them. If that's really the main motivation, some elucidation might help.

Comment: one example could be [ring](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring) middleware (similar to Servlet filters), with which you can enrich a map describing an HTTP request. Namespaced keys allow you to write your custom middleware to add extra values without worrying about interferences with any other middleware configured in your ring app.

Answer (score 31):

As now documented [for Clojure](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_literals) as well as [for ClojureScript](https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/keyword-qualify), `::` keywords can also be used to resolve namespace aliases.  For example, `::foo/bar` will evaluate to `:clojure.core/bar` if `foo` is an alias of `clojure.core`. Reader exception is thrown if `foo` does not resolve to a namespace.

Comment: That feature is documented there
- https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_literals
- https://cljs.github.io/api/syntax/keyword-qualify

Comment: Also relevant, since Clojure 1.9, is `#:` and `#::` syntax, which is used together with a map to resolve the keywords _inside_ the map, as explained [here](https://clojure.org/guides/weird_characters#_and_namespace_map_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

The **`::`** is for a *"Fully-Qualified NameSpace"*, or FQNS as I like to call
it, similar in concept to a
[FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). It (`::`)
"expands" to either a "required alias" (eg, `::str` is an alias to the dotted
part of `(:require [clojure.string :as str])`), or the current NS it's in (eg,
`::` is an alias to the `(ns myproj.myns ...)` at the top of the current
file). It resolves to having a `/`, as compared to a bare key resolving with
no `/`.

### Comparing shapes of FQNSs

A FQNS (having or resolving to contain a `/`) can take a few shapes, and should be
looked at in comparison to the basic "unqualified" keyword syntax that uses a
single `:` and no `/`. FQNS "shortcut" keyword syntax uses leading colons
(`::`).

#### Short-form shortcut (`::k` is "local" and `::aa/k` is "aliased")

These are "expanded" to a full NS as described above. *Think of the `::` as
representing a full long name being squeezed.* They *can* contain dots
but I feel dashes are clearer. Note that the latter contains a `/`.

#### Long-form explicit (`:bb.cc.dd/k`)

These are fully spelled out, explicit with dots and dashes in meaningful ways
to represent namespaces containing the keys. The dots are a low-level
(filesystem) detail, but represent the hierarchy of parent(s)/child, wherein
`aa.bb.cc` is `aa` as grand-parent, `bb` as parent, and `cc` as child. An
"explicit" FQNS has a single `:` but contains a `/` (eg, `:aa/bb`,
`:cc.dd/ee`).

#### Bare, basic, unqualified (`:k`)

This is the basic unqualified key you've known about from day-1.

I find it helpful to have your editor make it obvious which shape you're
observing. Here you can see in the screenshot that the `::` is *red* for the
current NS, the explicit full NS is *blue*, the "aliased" NS is *green*, and the
final "key" is *purple*.

[image: Emacs screenshot with colored key syntax]

### Full example

Notice in this example (which you can play with in a REPL) how these "resolve"
(see trailing comments). There are more than a dozen cases here that are all a
little different.

```clj
(ns proj.ns1)
(ns proj.area.ns2)
(ns proj.ns3
  (:require
   [clojure.string   :as str]
   [clojure.data.avl :as d-a]   ; or da or avl or just a; be consistent across code base
   [clojure.data.zip :as d.z]   ; using dots in alias is confusing IMO
   [proj.area.ns2    :as ns2]   ; some fns being used
   [proj.ns1   :as-alias ns3])) ; keying convenience, new in v1.11, avoids circular deps

(def m "A contrived map demonstrating various key shapes"
  {:aa               "good"  ;=> :aa                      ; typical: basic unqualified key
   ::bb              "good"  ;=> :proj.ns3/bb             ; typical: note that / is implicitly added
   ::str             "bad"   ;=> :proj.ns3/str            ; missing key
   :ns3/cc           "weird" ;=> :ns3/cc                  ; missing full ns despite alias
   :proj.area.ns4/dd "ok"    ;=> :proj.area.ns4.dd        ; ns might not exist but ok
   ::ns2/ff          "good"  ;=> :proj.area.ns2/ff        ; common practice
   :proj.area.ns2/gg "ok"    ;=> :proj.area.ns2/gg        ; but this is why we have `:as-alias`
   :proj.ns1/hh      "bad"   ;=> :proj.ns1/hh             ; clearer to just use `::` for cur ns
   :str/ii           "bad"   ;=> :str/ii                  ; an accident: str not expanded
   ::str/jj          "good"  ;=> :clojure.string/jj       ; and typical
   ::kk.ll           "so-so" ;=> :proj.ns3/kk.ll          ; confusing to have dots in actual key
   ::d-a/mm.nn       "so-so" ;=> :clojure.data.json/mm.nn ; again, dots in key
   ::d-a/oo          "good"  ;=> :clojure.data.json/oo    ; typical
   ::d.z/pp          "so-so" ;=> :proj.ns3/pp             ; dots in qualifier diff from ns structure
   :random/qq        "good"  ;=> :random/qq               ; qualified, but not a real ns
   :other.random/rr  "good"  ;=> :other.random/rr         ; qualified, but not a real ns
   })
```

Note that these are all new keys you're "making". The `:jj` key doesn't actually
exist in the `clojure.string` NS, but that doesn't stop you from using it.

### Distilled

One of the most surprising things is that a `/` is added in the expansion in
the local uses (`::`). So these three are the ones to focus on remembering:

```
WRITTEN     RESOLVED
:aa      => :aa (bare)
::bb     => :proj.ns1/bb (qualified)
::ns3/cc => :proj.ns3/cc (qualified, slash explicit)
```

On the left side:

- `aa` and `bb` look almost identical, but resolve very differently
- `bb` and `cc` look quite different, but they're actually resolving very similarly

I somewhat wish there was `::/foo` instead of `::foo` since the implicit `/`
in the latter is what makes the system feel irregular.

It's important to know most of these FQNS cases when you're using libraries
like [malli](https://github.com/metosin/malli) or
[spec](https://clojure.org/about/spec) or
[integrant](https://github.com/weavejester/integrant) or various others, since
they make liberal use of FQNSs. And for any sizeable project, it usually
becomes necessary to qualify some keys to avoid collisions.

### Destructuring

Note the use of `:keys` and selection with `:`, `::`, and neither in
destructuring with these.

```clj
(let [{:keys [aa]} m]               aa) ; "good" (typical)
(let [{:keys [:aa]} m]              aa) ; "good" (also works with :)
(let [{:keys [::aa]} m]             aa) ; nil
(let [{:keys [::bb]} m]             bb) ; "good"
(let [{:keys [ns2/ff]} m]           ff) ; nil
(let [{:keys [:ns2/ff]} m]          ff) ; nil
(let [{:keys [::ns2/ff]} m]         ff) ; "good"
(let [{:keys [ns3/cc]} m]           cc) ; "weird"
(let [{:keys [:ns3/cc]} m]          cc) ; "weird"
(let [{:keys [other.random/rr]} m]  rr) ; "good"
(let [{:keys [:other.random/rr]} m] rr) ; "good"
```

### Conclusion

This is a tricky area of Clojure syntax to keep straight, yet it is an
essential part of everyday code. It helps reduce confusion if you follow NS
style guides such as these:

- [Clojure Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#namespace-declaration)
- [How to ns](https://stuartsierra.com/2016/clojure-how-to-ns.html)

Note that there may be disagreement here around aliasing conventions (`str` vs
`string`, dots in aliases, etc), but the key is to settle your code base
conventions on *your* rules and stay consistent.